# Xamarin auto permissions grantee without permission dialog

Tags: xamarin, android-permissions

When we download Whatsapp, it automatically guarantees the permissions itself without showing us the permission dialog. How can I do this in Xamarin? my platform is Android.

Comment: which permission are you talking about?

Comment: Camera and writing external storage  @Jason

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to bypass this.  Older versions of Android simply prompted the user at install to allow whatever permissions the app needed.  More recently, there is a granular request for specific permissions.  If an App was able to access the camera without the users permission, that would be a HUGE security flaw.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if your device is rooted this could be possible. Otherwise, the answer is no.

Ever since API 23 (Android 6 Marshmallow), App permissions have been a thing. If your App targets API 23 or higher, this is something you have to support and ask for whenever you do something that is marked "dangerous". These are permissions for stuff that could involve personal information about the user of the device. You can read more about [permission levels in the official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous).